# Transferring Data from one table to another

Tags: sql

I need help with my sql code, is there a way for me to transfer the data from "AS subtotal" from the first SELECT statement to the "receipt.totalAmount" from the second SELECT statement. Kind of new with sql I tried to look it up online but I didn't see any solution for it. I can't declare subtotal from the first SELECT statement to the second SELECT statement. Also is it possible to sum up all the subtotals to the total column?

```
SELECT productServices.productId, productServices.proPrice, orders.orderId, orders.quantity, productServices.proPrice*orders.quantity AS subtotal , orders.dateOrdered
FROM productServices
JOIN orders
ON productServices.productId=orders.productId



SELECT receipt.receiptNo, receipt.customerId, receipt.orderId, receipt.employeeId, receipt.totalAmount, receipt.paymentMethod, receipt.dateOfPurchase
FROM receipt
JOIN customerInfo ON customerInfo.customerId=receipt.customerId
JOIN employeeInfo ON employeeInfo.employeeId=receipt.employeeId
JOIN orders ON orders.orderId=receipt.orderId
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it into a single select statement.  Something like this. Or use inner queries to get what you need.

```
SELECT receipt.receiptNo, receipt.customerId, receipt.orderId, receipt.employeeId, receipt.totalAmount, receipt.paymentMethod, receipt.dateOfPurchase,
productServices.productId, productServices.proPrice, orders.orderId, orders.quantity, productServices.proPrice*orders.quantity AS subtotal , orders.dateOrdered
FROM receipt
JOIN customerInfo ON customerInfo.customerId=receipt.customerId
JOIN employeeInfo ON employeeInfo.employeeId=receipt.employeeId
JOIN orders ON orders.orderId=receipt.orderId
JOIN productServices on productServices.productid = orders.productid
```